# Is there a limit to adding hero names, and could adding/removing the names often break the game?

Tags: rogue-legacy

For those who don't know if you go to *Rogue Legacy>Content* you can find two files that allow you to change the names of heroes and heroines you get to play with.

Now i know there is a limit to the amount of characters that can be used in the name (8), but is there a limit to the amount of names you can add to the list?

Also can changing (both adding and removing of the names) that file often break the game in any way? Or is it completely safe to change the file as much as you want, whenever you want.

Comment: I did not know this. This is the best thing ever. I shall now name all characters after people on Arqade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the only limitation to how many names you can have there is how much space you have left on your computer so... shitloads.

And removing names just removes any probability of that name appearing on any of your future knights, the textfile has nothing to do with the savefiles at all.